# Laravel DomPDF view not found

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

At the moment I am trying to generate a PDF in laravel using the DomPDF library. This is the code that I have so far:

Controller class:

```
    public function downloadPDF($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.cardsReport', $user);

        return $pdf->download('cards.pdf');
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/downloadPDF/{id}','EditController@downloadPDF');
```

View - cardReport.blade.php(inside pdf folder):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td><b>User</b></td>
        <td><b>Email</b></td>
        <td><b>Phone Number</b></td>     
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{$user->name}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{$user->email}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{$user->phone_number}}
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error that appears is view not found (pdf.cardsReport) which I'm not sure why it is appearing as the view itself exists?

Comment: `\PDF::loadView('pdf.cardsReport', $user);`  add `\PDF::` not `PDF::
`

Comment: When I put `\PDF::` instead it appears as undefined class PDF

Comment: you are loading `cardsReport` but you have written the file name as View - cardReport.blade.php , is it missing `s`